# Jquery Map function with TD and Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to combine the words in td and input text entered in the textbox.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td class="CommentWords" width="25%">jsakldjs </td>
  <td class="Label" width="85%"> <input class="Textcomment"
      id="txtCommentWords_3" type="text" width="550px">
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="NormalItem">
    <td class="CommentWords" width="25%">klsajdksajd </td>
    <td class="Label" width="85%"> <input class="Textcomment"
        id="txtCommentWords_4" type="text" width="550px"> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

as i need to select all words from "commentWords" and  "TextComment class", with associated values. 
[Fiddler link.](http://jsfiddle.net/23hgy/1/)

for eg:

**output will be**

> jsakldjs Å InputTextvalue ¶   // Å will be Field separator,     ¶ will be Row Seperator

this what i tried, but as of now it wil return either textbox value or td value. i need to get all td value with corrsponding text values with field and row separator

```
var list = $(".CommentWords, .Textcomment", this).map(function() {
                            return $(this).val();
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like

```
var list = $(".CommentWords, .Textcomment", $('#table')).map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('td')) {
        return $this.text();
    } else {
        return $this.val();
    }
});
```

Print the results

```
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var current  = list[i];
    $('#result').append(current);
    if(i % 2 !== 0){
        $('#result').append(' [end of line] ');
    }else{
         $('#result').append(' [td - input separetor] ');
    }
}
```

if you need to conactenate a string

```
 var finalString = '';
 for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var current  = list[i];
    finalString  += current;
    if(i % 2 !== 0){
        finalString += ' [end of line] ';
    }else{
        finalString += ' [td - input separetor] ';
    }
 }
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/23hgy/2/

Comment: i need to join with field and row seperator

Comment: @Ravi i added that, look at the fiddle, i also added a method to concatenate in a string

Answer (score 2):

The text of the `<td>` is retrieved using the `text()` function. I made a fiddle to show you:

http://jsfiddle.net/U9xnj/1/

basically, you can do this, but it is not very readable:

```
var list = $(".CommentWords, .Textcomment").map(function() {
                            return $(this).text() || $(this).val();
                        });
```

Comment: Both answers are good, but yours is much nicer. Just in style of `jQuery`

Comment: i need to join with field and row seperator wich i mentioned above

Comment: @Ravi Just use `var joined = list.join("your separator")`

Comment: @Oybek no he  needs to join in a different way